# How to convert grinning face  into its unicode code point (U+1F600)

Tags: c#, unicode, emoji

How can i convert this emoji  into its unicode code point in c#?

Its unicode code point is **U+1F600**

I have tried encode decoding (`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("")`)

It becomes `&#128512;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`128512` is a decimal equivalent of `0x1F600`. Alternatively, you could consider

```
var x = Char.ConvertToUtf32("", 0);
```

Comment: ty but it needs additional step just found it :D string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");

Comment: Not my downvote, but OP already have similar result that they did not like - `Char.ConvertToUtf32("", 0)` returns 128512 (as expected). So you may want to clarify what question you've actually answered.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just edited the post, and than read your comment :). Thanks!

Comment: I also do not understand the downvoting people. I have figured out need to hexvalue after asked the question.